# Branch contains commits from master

Tags: git, github

I've just made a pull request for my branch and for unknown reason my the pull request contains all the commits from the master(in addition to my branch commits)

Do anybody have an idea for the reason for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might have pulled branch master to your branch (git pull origin master).

If you did that, it will place all master commits on top of your branch.

Take a look at your git log output or gitk to see when it was merged.

Answer (score 0):

> I've just made a pull request for my branch and for unknown reason my the pull request contains all the commits from the master

verify that you did not merged master into your branch with:

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline
```